# How to hide status bar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-statusbar

How can I hide the status bar for a specific activity?

I found this similar question, but none of the answers worked for me. The app just crashed every time I tried to go to the activity:
[How to hide status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android)

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692388/android-remove-actionbar-title-keeping-toolbar-menu/33692402#33692402

Comment: Status bar is what I want removed, not action bar.

Answer (score 23):

Try this in you activity before setting your content

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: That worked, but does it work for all versions of Android?

Answer (score 4):

**Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and Lower**

1. By setting the theme of application in manifest.xml file.

   ```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
   ```

   OR
2. By writing JAVA code in activity's onCreate() method.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
       // the status bar.
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       }
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
   ```

**Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher**

By writing JAVA code in Activity's onCreate() method.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)//before Jelly Bean Versions
{ 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
else // Jelly Bean and up
{ 
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int ui = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(ui);

    //Hide actionbar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

Comment: Not working for me on Android 9... The app is in Full Screen but the statusBar shows up. Any idea ?

Comment: Please add these before  setContentView in OnCreate

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.toolbar_color));
        }

Answer (score 0):

Only working answer (for me at least)

In styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

The in-code solution did not work for me in 4.4.2 Kitkat.

Answer (score -1):

Open styles.xml and update the styles which your activity uses :

```
<style name="ExampleTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> <!-- add this line -->
</style>
```