# Above the title bar

Tags: android

How can I hide the battery, connection, wi-fi ... etc (Status Bar) which are above on the top of the smartphone? I removed the title bar by

```
<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

Comment: That bar is called Status Bar.

Comment: Read this official documentation at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Comment: See this https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide status bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705720/how-to-hide-status-bar)

Answer (score 1):

**style.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".FullScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @SaherS Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 lines inside `onCreate` method before setting content view:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the status bar on Android 4.0 and above do this

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Check out this link for more info
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_hotel_image);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: wc bro please rate me up bro